# Syntax error when starting powershell from bat file

Tags: powershell, command-line

I want to start a powershell script with RunAs from a bat file. This works.

```
@echo
SET "InstallerFolder=\\dc01\e\script"

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%InstallerFolder%\Script.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

But if i add:

```
-RedirectStandardOutput ""%InstallerFolder%\node.txt""
```

It breaks.

So the line looks like this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-RedirectStandardOutput ""%InstallerFolder%\node.txt"" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%InstallerFolder%\TSM Client Install Script.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

And resuslts in an powershell error which is gone so fast i can't see it.
Probably syntax?

Help much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Add `-NoExit` parameter to Powershell, so it won't exit and you can read the error message.

Comment: To where? I'm getting errors when i do that:
    A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'noexit'.

Comment: As you didn't tell where you tried to add the switch, read Powershell.exe's [help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) and look for correct syntax.

Comment: I tried every thinkable place. After First powershell, after second, inside argumentlist. No Dice. The help documentation does not provide any help on this.

Comment: Of source if i remove the redirectstandardoutput the -noexit works fine. But then it doesn't really matter..

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `powershell.exe` does not have a `-RedirectStandardOuptut` parameter. (See [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)).

Also your syntax is way off (but since i dont see any reason to start powershell to start powershell again i wont bother explaining the syntax errors).

If you want to use RunAs from the cmd use it directly. For more info see [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) (again).

Also you can redirect output in Batch Files with `>` or `>>` if you want to append.

Comment: I don't want the output from the .bat file. No powershell does not have a parameter called -RedirectStandardOuptut, but start-process does have an argument called that. I need to start prowershell twice so i can use RunAs. I don't think you understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: @user3019059 Either that or You dont get my answer. You want to redirect the output of the powershell instance you start? As my answer states you could just use runas from your bat and redirect from there. In case you for some reason still have to use your approach just get your syntax right! In your example code you are passing the -redirect... As parameter for powershell.exe which obviously doesn't work

Comment: If I add it to the argumentlist I get syntax error.  And I  don't know why, and I can't see the error.

Comment: @user3019059 You have to add it as parameter for start-process, the argumentlist parameter contains the parameters you pass to the process

Comment: PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList ' -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%InstallerFolder%\TSM Client Install Script.ps1""' -RedirectStandardOutput ""%InstallerFolder%\node.txt"" -Verb RunAs}"; Which is here? that doesn't work either.

Comment: @user3019059 PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {$f = ""%InstallerFolder%\TSM Client Install Script.ps1""; $out = ""%InstallerFolder%\node.txt""; Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @("-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File $($f)","-RedirectStandardOutput $($out)" ,"-Verb RunAs"}" try something like this. (havent actually tested it, might not be perfect syntax). also did you check if the installerfolder variable is passed correctly ?

Comment: Thank you for your time. No dice unfortunately:
The string starting:
At line:1 char:9
+ & {$f =  <<<< "\\dc01\e\script\Script.ps1; $out = \\dc01\e\script\node.txt; Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @(-NoProfile, -ExecutionPolicy Bypass, -File $
($f),-RedirectStandardOutput $($out) ,-Verb RunAs}
is missing the terminator: ".

Comment: At line:1 char:282
+ & {$f = "\\dc01\e\script\Script.ps1; $out = \\dc01\e\script\TSM-Udrulning
sscript-BA-Client\node.txt; Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @(-NoProfile, -ExecutionPolicy Bypass, -File $($f),-
RedirectStandardOutput $($out) ,-Verb RunAs}  <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (\\dc01\e\script\Sc... ,-Verb RunAs} :String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: @user3019059 that is because you have to close your double quotes (line 1, variable $f). Do you even try to solve problems by yourself? The Error message in this case should be enough